# Post content doesn't breaking?

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger

I have a blogger blog,I am using a template everything is right but when i post on it my post content doesn't breaking.it is overlapping its section and whole webpage so that horizontal scroll bar comes below the web page.
[image: The problem]

```
<div class="post-body entry-content">
This is my post content
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn    nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is issue with long words only.

Try to set `word-break: break-all;` for `.entry-content` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's issue coming when you wrote long word without spacing.

For that add CSS for that:

```
.entry-content{
  word-break:break-all;
}
```